# What Is The Better Way To Customize A Core Block's After Prepare Layout in Magento?

Tags: magento

All blocks in Magento inherit from the abstract, and inside the fragment of code:

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php   
public function setLayout(Mage_Core_Model_Layout $layout)
{
    $this->_layout = $layout;
    Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before', array('block' => $this));
    $this->_prepareLayout();
    Mage::dispatchEvent('core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after', array('block' => $this));
    return $this;
}
```

There are two ways to hook onto a prepare layout of a core block:

1. Rewrite the core block to your own and create the _prepareLayout function calling it's parent and then doing your code after
2. Observe the core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_after event and check if the instance of the block is the one your interested in

The advantage to the second is that event/observer patterns are the better, more stable choice for implementing additional functionality.
However, the disadvantage is that the observer would have to run for *every single block* whose layout is prepared.

Which is the better progamming technique here?

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite the Abstract class most block will still use the one in core, because they directly extend from it and don't use the Magento rewrite rules.
So I would do it with your second solution. Even with the observer on every block the performance issue should not be that big, because in most cases you will just execute a simple condition with instanceof, which is really fast.